# Sybase - Filtering only the first 24 hours of data from DATETIME field

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I have a problem at the moment.  I have a database table which is populated every couple of minutes with rows of data based on patient care.  One of the columns is a DATETIME (Timestamp) field called 'AdmissionTime' which shows when the data was captured.  This information is based on a patient by patient basis so the table grows quite large.  Patients are determined by patientID field....so its easy to filter per patient

What I would like to do though is only show the first 24 hours of this data from the first TIMESTAMP created by the patient activity.....i.e. it could be that this data is collected for 4 or 5 days but I only want the first 24 hours worth of data

e.g.

```
Patient is admitted - first timestamp captured at Jan 01, 2013 7:20pm

|
| I want all the data in between
| 
V
Jan 02, 2013 7:19pm
```

Any ideas.

Many thanks in advance.

Regards

Gareth

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this ?

```
select * from table
where patientID = patientYouWant
and AdmissionTime <= dateadd(day, 1, (select min(AdmissionTime) from table where patientID = patientYouWant)
```

Comment: I'll give this a try mate. I did notice that you have put 'Admission <= ' while selecting the MIN value. Should this not be >= ?

Comment: Well, you want anything that is lower or equal to the first AdmissionTime + one day.